# SQLite database Insert query not working for ionic app

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add cordova SQLite database in my ionic project which is scanning qrcode & inserting details into local database.

My database initialization is this:

```
var db = null;
var app = angular.module('scanstarter', ['ionic', 'ionic-material', 'ngCordova']);

app.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaSQLite) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        // Sqlite database initialization
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'scanstarter.db'});
        // create table for product scan
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productScan (id integer primary key, unique_id text, productName text, serialNo text, manufacturer text, department text, time text, latitude text, longitude text, actionRequired text, sync text)");
        // create table for comments
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (id integer primary key, unique_id text, comment text)");
    }, false);
});
```

})

My scan function flow is this:

```
    $scope.goToScan = function () {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                if (!result.cancelled)
                {
                    if (result.format == "QR_CODE")
                    {
                        var scannedData = result.text;

                        var posOptions = {enableHighAccuracy: true};
                        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
                            //Get latitude and longitude
                            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                            //Initial Split with #
                            var splitArray = scannedData.split("#");
                            var UniqueId = splitArray[0];
                            var ProductName = splitArray[1];
                            var SerialNo = splitArray[2];
                            var Manufacturer = splitArray[3];
                            var Department = splitArray[4];
                            //Individual Split with :
                            var UniqueIdArray = UniqueId.split(':');
                            var ProductNameArray = ProductName.split(':');
                            var SerialNoArray = SerialNo.split(':');
                            var ManufacturerArray = Manufacturer.split(':');
                            var DepartmentArray = Department.split(':');

                            if ((UniqueIdArray[0] == 'unique_id') && (ProductNameArray[0] == 'product_name') && (SerialNoArray[0] == 'serial_no') && (ManufacturerArray[0] == 'manufacturer') && (DepartmentArray[0] == 'department')) {
//Insert query part start
                                var query = "INSERT INTO productScan (unique_id, productName, serialNo, manufacturer, department, time, latitude, longitude, actionRequired, sync) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [UniqueIdArray[1], ProductNameArray[1], SerialNoArray[1], ManufacturerArray[1], DepartmentArray[1], Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), latitude, longitude, 'N', 'N']).then(function (res) {
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(res));

                                }, function (err) {
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                                });
//Insert query part end
                                $state.go('app.scan');

                            } else {
                                alert('Invalid QR-Code. This QR-Code is not part of Inventory!.');
                            }

                        }, function (err) {
                            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Kindly check your mobile GPS. GPS must be on!.'});
                            $timeout(function () { // server replies when username or password is incorrect
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                            }, 3000)
                        });

                    }
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            }
    );
}
```

what happens is when i comment the insert query part of cordovaSQLite and build the app and check it then it successfully scan and then navigates to next page. But when i uncomment it and build the apk and run it on my mobile it does not navigate me to next page. I saw the flow working by adding subsequent alerts after each modile of execution and then i found that i am getting stuck at the point where sqlite insert query code starts.

What is the error occuring here i am really not getting. Is there something i am missing?

Thanks in advance for quick response.

**UPDATE**

Basic example is here
The controller code is this

```
    $scope.insert = function (firstname, lastname) {
    alert('HI'+firstname+' '+lastname);
    var query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [firstname, lastname]).then(function (res) {
        alert('HI2');
        alert("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
    }, function (err) {
        alert(err);
    });
}

$scope.select = function (lastname) {
    alert('HI'+lastname);
    var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [lastname]).then(function (res) {
        alert('HI');
        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
            alert("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + res.rows.item(0).lastname);
        } else {
            alert("No results found");
        }
    }, function (err) {
        alert(err);
    });
}
```

View looks like this:

```
    <button class="button button-block button-small button-energized" ng-click="insert('sagar', 'barawade')">INSERT</button>
    <button class="button button-block button-small button-energized" ng-click="select('barawade')">SELECT</button>
```

Initialization is same as given above.

On this code even i am not able to get the alerts for inserted id & also nothing for select query as response.

Comment: What error message gets returned?

Comment: actually nothing is getting returned. it directly stop their and does not navigate me to next view.

Comment: if i comment the Insert query part and run it then it navigates me to app.scan view

Comment: wrap it in a JavaScript try catch and see if anything gets caught?... `try { //insert sqlite code... } catch (err) { alert(err.message); }`

Comment: hey i have tried your suggestion in the exception it is showing me "cannot read property transaction of null"........what does it mean

Comment: Sounds like your db variable is null so when you try to do a transaction it wont work. Try doing the same JavaScript try catch statement around your db initialisation because there might be an error when you open it... `db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'scanstarter.db'});`

Comment: Hey it shows me error "Error: Database location or iosDatabaseLocation value is now mandatory in openDatabase call" in the try catch as u suggested.

Comment: I hound the resolutions ur suggestions were really helpful

Comment: I thought it would be that, I got that error last week haha. It's a recent (breaking) update that the plugin maintainer introduced

Comment: Yes but at the same time that update should also be reflected to ngCordova site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it finally after a weeks long efforts.

I need to specify the database like the following way

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "biziscan.db", location: 1, iosDatabaseLocation: 'default'});
```

Need to specify the default location for database. It is their in the github file of plugin but has not got updated in the ngCordova site.

Answer (score 1):

while creating table, for time column you have given text as datatype. But while inserting u are inserting a integer. Please check that

Comment: thanks for your response but even i turned for trying a basic example where i created the same db and just tried adding sample data as shown in this link https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/ still it doesn't work.

Comment: i have added the basic example too. u can check the update part

Comment: is that going into success block or not...? or you are getting any error? can u post your log data?

Comment: Neither success block executes nor the error block. Just a screen is displayed as the alert i have set to verify whether the function is calling or not.

Comment: is there any version issue??.. My android version was 4.0.2 which i am updating now while my ionic CLI verison is 1.7.14.

Comment: check this sample project.... https://github.com/haritha-u/SQLite-DataBase-Sample

Comment: platform android was not their. i have added & built & tried...same problem coming. In your case even the initial alert section before operation i cant see on the app. I guess this could be an issue with latest android-ionic versions...